# Adding r^2 value to a graph with multiple datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, graph

Does anyone know how I can add an r^2 value to each of my lines on this graph with three different datasets? I used the ggplot2 and dplyr packages.
Here's my code. I'm sort of new to so apologies if the answer is super obvious lol.

```
colours <- c("Crustiose" = "cadetblue", "Foliose" = "goldenrod1", "Fruticose" = "indianred")
data1<- lichendata %>% group_by(Elevation_Avg, Relative_Abundance_CR)
data2<- lichendata %>% group_by(Elevation_Avg, Relative_Abundance_FO)
data3<- lichendata %>% group_by(Elevation_Avg, Relative_Abundance_FR)
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = data1, aes(x = Elevation_Avg, y = Relative_Abundance_CR, colour = "Crustiose")) + 
  geom_smooth(data = data1, aes(x = Elevation_Avg, y = Relative_Abundance_CR), method ="lm", se = FALSE, colour = "cadetblue") +
   geom_point(data = data2, aes(x = Elevation_Avg, y = Relative_Abundance_FO, colour = "Foliose")) +
  geom_smooth(data = data2, aes(x = Elevation_Avg, y = Relative_Abundance_FO),method = "lm", se = FALSE, colour = "goldenrod1") +
  geom_point(data = data3, aes(x = Elevation_Avg, y = Relative_Abundance_FR, colour = "Fruticose")) + 
  geom_smooth(data = data3, aes(x = Elevation_Avg, y = Relative_Abundance_FR), method = "lm", se = FALSE, colour = "indianred") +
 labs( x = "Average Elevation (m)", y = "Relative Abundance", colour = "Growth Form") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = colours)
```

I tried playing with the lm_eq section but I couldn't get it to show up on the graph for some reason. Maybe I'm calling the wrong dataset? Here's my graph without.

[image]

Comment: Hi Zoey, do you think you could edit your question to be reproducible? In this context, it may be best to use an embedded R dataset like `mtcars` or `ToothGrowth`. You could also share `dput(data1)` and so on for data sets 1-3. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a combination of stat_poly_line and stat_poly_eq from the ggmisc https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpmisc/ggpmisc.pdf package should do what you are looking for. I also think you could make things a little easier by converting your data set to a long format rather than splitting into 3 seperate data sets:

```
    data1<- lichendata %>% pivot_longer(cols= c("Relative_Abundance_CR", "Relative_Abundance_FO", "Relative_Abundance_FR"), names_to="type", values_to="Relative_Abundance")

data1 %>% ggplot(aes(Elevation_Avg,Relative_Abundance, colour=type))+geom_point()+stat_poly_line(se=F)+stat_poly_eq()
```

)
You will still need tweak the formatting of which colours etc... to your liking.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @bevan while this provides useful tips, this doesn't provide an answer to the question. Could you edit your answer to demonstrate how the relevant functions you mentioned could be used in this context?